# symfony 1.4: doctrine build model warning

Tags: build, model, symfony1, doctrine, package

I copied my sources from my lokal dev (everything works fine) to my repository and from there I did a checkout on my remote dev.

Now when I try to build everything I get this error:

> devel:/var/www/myproject# ./symfony
>   doc:build-model
>
> > > doctrine  generating model classes
> > >       file+     /tmp/doctrine_schema_48726.yml
>
> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(/var/www/myproject/lib/model/doctrine//base/BaseAdvert.class.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in
>   /var/www/myproject/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/task/sfDoctrineBuildModelTask.class.php
>   on line 77

Do you know what the problem could be?

Thx for your answers :)

Comment: I found this http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DC-143 It seems to be the problem. But I don't want to remove the package definitions. I'm wondering why it works on my other dev environment without these warnings.

Answer (score 1):

you can fix this by changing your packagename in schema.yml from

```
detect_relations: ...
options:
  type: ....

package: yourpackagename
```

to

```
package: yourpackagename.foobar
```

The modelgenerator expects an point in the name of the package

look at your /var/www/myproject/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/task/sfDoctrineBuildModelTask.class.php on line 77

you will find something like this

```
... isset($definition['package']) ? '/'.substr($definition['package'], 0, strpos($definition['package'], '.'))....
```

Answer (score 0):

I now just removed the package definitions in the schema files, now it works. Doctrine seems to have problem with it. :-/